# How to manage multiple Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way to manage multiple Rails applications?

I heard Rack is a good tool to use and I was wondering if all Rails apps can share the same session so the users don't have to login twice.

I'm also using EmberJS aswell.

Comment: What do mean, "manage multiple applications"?

Comment: Manage their source?  Their deployment?  The running servers?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have two Rails apps that have separate logins using Devise, Cancan and Rolify. I want to use them together so users log into one system and use all the features of the other app. Is it better to use API instead with JSONP to exchange data?

Comment: I imagine that if you stored your sessions in a database and had secret keys of applications equal each other, users would be able to re-use their logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using token-based authentication, you can maintain a single database table for the user model across both apps (have them both connect to the same database, prefix all tables for app 1 with `app1_` and for app 2 with `app2_`, except for the User table which is unprefixed).

To prefix all the tables for one app, you can set

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = "app1_"
```

in the `environments.rb` file of app 1, and

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = "app2_"
```

in the `environments.rb` file of app 2.

Comment: As a matter of interest, how are you handling authorisation with Devise, Cancan, Rolify and EmberJS? I'm working on something similar.

Comment: And as Sergio said in the comments under your original question, you'll need to set both Devise instances to use the same secret key (use the same key for both).